# Proper vertx versions for push notifications

Tags: java, push-notification, vert.x

I tried to run next code, but for *2.1.6* vertex library occurs io.vertx package not found problem.
Or if somebody have a small project with Java and JS code for this, give please a link.
Also I tried *3.x.x* version, but it has no io.vertx method.

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import org.vertx.java.core.sockjs.SockJSServer;
import org.vertx.java.core.sockjs.impl.DefaultSockJSServer;
//...
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.newVertx();
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus()
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    JsonArray permitted = new JsonArray();
    permitted.add(new JsonObject());
    SockJSServer sockJSServer = new DefaultSockJSServer(vertx, server);
    sockJSServer.bridge(new JsonObject().putString("prefix", "/pusher"), permitted, permitted);
    server.listen(<some port>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vert.x versions 2.x used the org.vertx package, whereas the 3.x branch uses io.vertx, this is why you're running into problems.

For version 2 there are some examples regarding the event bus bridge:
https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/tree/master/src/raw/java/eventbusbridge

And a lot of examples for Vert.x 3:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples

So basically you should just stick to one of the versions and you should be fine.